# Inaccurate plot

Tags: plotting

Could someone please tell me how I can increase the accuracy of this plot, please? Or is there some other reason the lines are breaking up?

```
m = 60;
ContourPlot[{Re[Table[BernoulliB[n, (x + I y)], {n, m, m}]], 
Im[Table[BernoulliB[n, (x + I y)], {n, m, m}]]}, {x, -5, 6}, {y, -10, 10}, 
AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `PlotPoints` option

Comment: In addition to PlotPoints, you can increase MaxRecursion too (carefully, increasing it by 1 at a time, as running time depends exponentially on this parameter).  Try `MaxRecursion -> 3` without touching PlotPoints.

Comment: `PlotPoints -> 200` fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already know from the comments, increasing `MaxRecursion` or `PlotPoints` helps, where I would prefer the first one.

In the case of your function, you can gain some speed by compiling the expression. Then, you can set `MaxRecursion` to a higher value and the plot is still reasonable fast. The code below runs in about 3 seconds here

```
m = 60;
With[{cf = (Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}, {y, _Real, 0}},
        #, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"] & /@

           Flatten[{Re[Table[BernoulliB[n, (x + I y)], {n, m, m}]], 
        Im[Table[BernoulliB[n, (x + I y)], {n, m, m}]]}])},
  (#1[args__?NumericQ] := #2[args]) & @@@ Transpose[{{f1, f2}, cf}]
  ];

ContourPlot[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, -5, 6}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Simple and fast solution

```
m = 60;
f = Evaluate@N@BernoulliB[m, #] &;

ContourPlot[{Re@f[x + I y], Im@f[x + I y]}, {x, -5, 6}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]

It has the same speed as halirutan's solution with `Compile`. I think it is because of auto-compilation.